# No puedo mantener servicio de windows dentro de un servidor

Tags: windows, windows-server

Desarrollé un servicio para consumir datos de Sqlserver dentro de un servidor de windows, todo funciona y pude ejecutar el servicio y usarlo mientras tengo mi sesión se usuario abierta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al momento de desconectarme el servicio de windows desaparece y deja de funcionar. Es un tema de permisos, pero no tengo muy claro cuales son los permisos que necesito para dejar el servicio siempre funcionando.

Comment: ¿Registraste el servicio? ¿Te aparece en la pantalla de *Servicios*?

Comment: Me aparece como servicio de windows. Pero al desconectarme desaparece, para poder hacer pruebas tengo que mantener la sesion abierta. No puede dejar nada corriendo dentro del servidor.

Comment: Necesitas que se ejecute automaticamente, la instalacion debe ser para todos no solo para tu usuario

Comment: Necesito ser administrador?